# Не работает xml-маппинг в Hibernate

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, java-8, аннотации

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: если в я пишу маппинги для сущностей в hibernate.cfg.xml, то их почему-то хибернейт игнорит и при компиляции программа падает с ошибкой `Unknown entity`. Сама часть с маппингом в cfg.xml выглядит следующим образом:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- ........ -->
        <mapping class="models.UserAccount"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Однако если мне вручную написать маппинг в конфигурации при получении SessionFactory:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
configuration.addAnnotatedClass(UserAccount.class);

// И далее из этой конфигурации получаем объект SessionFactory
```

Тогда все работает прекрасно. Однако же не буду я в классе, который просто создает/передает объект SessionFactory писать сотню строк кода с добавлением AnnotatedClass'ов. Так вот, в чем моя ошибка? Что я делаю не так? В примерах вроде бы все так же, как у меня и написано, но только почему-то у меня это не работает.

Comment: Вам надо использовать один из способов маппинга сущностей. Если в

Answer (score 0):

Используйте аннотацию @Entity public class UserAccount{...}
Маппинги в xml прописывать не надо.
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/quickstart/html_single/#tutorial_annotations

Используйте AnnotationConfiguration вместо Configuration

```
   sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
                .configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

подробнее здесь https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#setup-configuration

Comment: Нет нет, я имею ввиду, что аннотациями у меня класс помечен, но его нужно еще добавить в конфигурацию, либо в xml файле, либо при создании SessionFactory у объекта Configuration (как у меня в вопросе), без этого будет ошибка Unknown Entity. И проблема в том, что у меня работает только способ с объектом Configuration, но не с xml

Comment: я дополнил ответ